Problemas con fetch js y laravel
Estoy intentando de enviar datos atravez de fetch hacia el controller,pero no puedo recorrer los datos en el backend  aqui el archivo js
if (e.target.matches(".btn-info")) {
    const idPerfilbtn = e.target.id
    e.preventDefault()
    var jsonObject = Object.assign({}, arrayPermisos);

    fetch('http://localhost/ventaLibro/public/permisosGuardar', {

        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute(
                'content')
        },
        'body': JSON.stringify({ 'jsonObjeto': jsonObject })

    }).then(function (response) {

        return response.json()

    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)

    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}

aqui el backend
 $dataObject = json_decode($request->jsonObjeto);

    foreach ($dataObject as $key => $value) {


        if ($value->estado == "eliminar") {
            $permiso = PermisosUsuarios::where('id_perfil',   7)->where('id_interfaces', $value->id)->get();
            $deletePermisos = PermisosUsuarios::findOrFail($permiso[0]['id']);
            $deletePermisos->delete();
        } else {
            $permiso = new PermisosUsuarios();
            $permiso->id_perfil =   7;
            $permiso->id_interfaces = $value->id;
            $permiso->save();
        }
    }
}

Aqui la pestaña de red en google
{jsonObjeto: {0: {id: "5", estado: "insertar"}, 1: {id: "6", estado: "insertar"}}}
jsonObjeto
:
{0: {id: "5", estado: "insertar"}, 1: {id: "6", estado: "insertar"}}
Aparece este error
permisosPerfiles.js:168
   POST http://localhost/ventaLibro/public/permisosGuardar 500 (Internal Server Error)

(anonymous) @ permisosPerfiles.js:168
permisosPerfiles.js:187 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Hola, creo que le falta un poco más de contexto a tu pregunta. Según entiendo, podrías verlo en los logs de Laravel. Un error 500 es un error de tu backend procesando la solicitud

Hola,estoy enviando un objeto a travez de fetch a un  controlador,me intencion es recorrer ese objeto en backend y registrar o  eliminar id_interfaz  segun el estado, lo habia realizado con ajax jquery y me funcionaba pero ahora no me funciona de esta forma

Lo solucione  quitando el json_decode
